# Flatten a named list in R

Tags: r, list, tags, dataframe, flatten

This is a very simple question, I can't believe I can't figure it out. I've searched high and low for a solution.

I have a named list, like so:

```
> fitted(mdl)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
-424.8135 -395.0308 -436.5832 -414.3145 -382.9686 -380.7277 -394.2808 -394.3340 
        9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16 
-401.6710 -386.6691 -407.4558 -427.4056 -397.4963 -415.6302 -436.1703 -378.4489 
       17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24 
-353.7718 -377.3190 -390.5177 -370.3608 -389.7843 -397.8872 -401.9937 -390.4119 
       25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32 
-387.4962 -422.4953 -427.1638 -402.5654 -409.6334 -360.7378 -355.1824 -370.9121 
       33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40 
-377.6591 -373.3049 -388.4417 -398.1172 -357.1107 -376.8618 -378.7070 -420.5362 
       41        42        43        44        45        46        47        48 
-390.8324 -406.5956 -403.1015 -363.5008 -347.2580 -371.0433 -376.4454 -360.3895 
       49 
-383.9711
```

`mdl` is an object returned from `lm()`, and I'm trying to extract the predicted values using the extractor function `fitted()`

I would like this to be without the `1,2,3,...` names. `str()` told me that `names` is an attribute. I can do

```
> names(fitted(mdl))
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
[16] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30"
[31] "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "37" "38" "39" "40" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45"
[46] "46" "47" "48" "49"
```

And that is what I want, except with the data. After trying various combinations of `unlist`,`cbind/rbind`, `do.call`, `c()`, etc. I finally figured out a solution:

```
> data.frame(fitted(mdl))$fitted.mdl
 [1] -424.8135 -395.0308 -436.5832 -414.3145 -382.9686 -380.7277 -394.2808
 [8] -394.3340 -401.6710 -386.6691 -407.4558 -427.4056 -397.4963 -415.6302
[15] -436.1703 -378.4489 -353.7718 -377.3190 -390.5177 -370.3608 -389.7843
[22] -397.8872 -401.9937 -390.4119 -387.4962 -422.4953 -427.1638 -402.5654
[29] -409.6334 -360.7378 -355.1824 -370.9121 -377.6591 -373.3049 -388.4417
[36] -398.1172 -357.1107 -376.8618 -378.7070 -420.5362 -390.8324 -406.5956
[43] -403.1015 -363.5008 -347.2580 -371.0433 -376.4454 -360.3895 -383.9711
```

But this is a very roundabout hack for something that must be right under my nose.

Any suggestions at what I'm missing?

(I don't know how to phrase the problem very well, or come up with a better title for the question, as I don't know the terminology to describe what I want. So feel free to edit :)

Comment: @SamuelTan Good job on asking your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to remove the `names` of the object, just use `unname`.

Here's a basic example:

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
fitted(lm.D9)
#     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13 
# 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 4.661 4.661 4.661 
#    14    15    16    17    18    19    20 
# 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661
```

Remove the names:

```
unname(fitted(lm.D9))
#  [1] 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 4.661 4.661 4.661
# [14] 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another simple way:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- rpois(5, 5)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(5)
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
fitted_ <- fitted(mod)
fitted_
   1        2        3        4        5 
# 7.822806 6.312569 9.333042 4.802333 9.333042 
names(fitted_) <- NULL
fitted_
# [1] 7.822806 6.312569 9.333042 4.802333 9.333042
```